Incorrect Terminal Prompt with Glitched venv Name on Mac with VSCode
Hello so I ended up glitching my terminal name somehow, here is how it looks right now
(venv) venv{myname}@{name} % while it should be (venv) {myname}@{name} %. This problem persists even when the virtual environment is not activated and only occurs in certain folders, while others display the prompt correctly.
Note: Im on Mac and im using Python + VSCode
Thanks
I tried researching more but couldn't find any solution, tried to ask ChatGPT but couldn't help.

The terminal prompt is typically configured with the PS1 environment variable.
If you have a line in your shell startup file that modifies PS1, that's likely where the issue is.

You can check the activate script in your virtual environment's bin directory to see if it modifies the PS1 variable.

wouldn't be the first bug this has had. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78294704/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78427653/11107541. if you raise an issue ticket, please add a link here to it.
